# What is the default timeout for a unit test in mstest?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

MSTest has a [TimeoutAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.timeoutattribute.aspx) that can be used to specify the test timeout.

But what happens if a test without that attribute doesn't finish? Is there a default timeout? And is the default the same when the test is run with mstest.exe or in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio, using a testsettings file, the default was 30 minutes.

In Visual studio, when using a runsettings file, it may be configurable.

Using microsoft testcases, add

```
    <MSTest>
     <TestTimeout>3600000</TestTimeout>
    </MSTest>
```

within the runsettings file, in order to set the default timeout for microsoft unit tests to 1 hour.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is 5 min, and so does this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b7d3a0a-cc58-4b86-8be0-385a4bde6d5c/mstestexe-default-configuration-file-to-resolve-the-timeout-error?forum=vststest) unless you are using ordered test, then it looks like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/02/16/ordered-test-timeout.aspx) (kind of old post, but it's not easy to find a good reference on it).

Comment: This is not the "default" behavior. If you open visual studio and just create a new unit test project and write this inside the test: `Thread.Sleep(600000);` - after 10 minutes the test will **pass**.